# xpath - show specific line (last) of a multiline node text

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Is it possible to show only a specific line of some node multiline content? I am parsing some junit.xml, and i want to show the last line of an `error` node. So for example for this data:

```
<testsuite>
<testcase>
<error message="test setup failure">some
lines 
of a lenghty
stacktrace
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
E   OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected</error>
</testcase>
<testcase>
<error message="test setup failure">some
lines 
of a lenghty
stacktrace
    raise Exception(&quot;Connection closed by remote!&quot;)
E   Exception: Connection closed by remote!</error>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
```

I'd like to show only

```
E   OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
E   Exception: Connection closed by remote!
```

getting the whole text is trivial by either

```
/testsuite/testcase/error/text()
//error/text()
```

I tried below xpath expressions:

```
//error/text()[last()]
```

but they dnt work. I was able to achieve what I wanted using xmlstarlet like so:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//error" -v "substring-after(., 'E   ')" -n
```

but I was wondering if is something like that possible to be achieved by pure XPath expression?

Comment: Just a question. Is it possible to find  "E " in "the lines of a lenghty stacktrace" ? Because "substring-after" will split at the first occurence. Maybe you should be more restrictive with something like this (we search for ")\nE") : `normalize-space(substring-after(.,concat(")",codepoints-to-string(10),"E")))`

Comment: I know, that why I treat my "sulution" more like a workaround. Well, in the error field there is standard pytest error trace. I guess that it is possible to have more than one `"^E   "`  - eg in case of a chained exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since xmlstarlet only supports XPath 1.0, but does support EXSLT extension functions, what I would recommend is using [str:tokenize()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) to tokenize the text and return the last token.

The EXSLT extension functions are supported in XPath using the "sel" command (-m and -v), but I was not able to get it to work. I think this is because of the way xmlstarlet creates the internal XSLT that is used.

I was able to get it to work using the "tr" command though by creating my own XSLT...

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" 
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt str">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//error">
      <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(.,'&#xA;')[last()]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xmlstarlet command line**

```
xmlstarlet tr test.xsl input.xml
```

**Output**

```
E   OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
E   Exception: Connection closed by remote!
```

If you're using something that supports XSLT 2.0, you could do something like this:

```xml
for $err in //error return tokenize($err, '&#xA;')[last()]
```

Note: You may have to change `&#xA;` to `\n` in some of the online XPath testers.

Comment: you;re right. I was trying some `tokenize` , but it didnt work on the page i mentioned in the other comment - probably xpath version is crucial here. Basically this: http://xpather.com/F36ICgLj works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using an xpath expression like

```
//testcase//error/substring-after(.,"E ")
```

The output should be:

```
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
Exception: Connection closed by remote!
```

Comment: Works from here : https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html Keep in mind that's an XPath 2.0 syntax. And I don't think xmlstarlet support it.

Comment: @murison The expression in action: http://xpather.com/7yNz4FHP

Comment: ok, you were both right. probably the xpath tester i was testing on is using xpath 1.0. Thanks for suggestions!. still, the `tokenize` approach proposed by @JackFleeting looks much better than this substring thing... so to sum up: http://xpather.com/F36ICgLj works like a charm ;)